# Γ-spaces and operads

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory, loop-spaces, operads

I'm looking for a comprehensible reference that explains how $\Gamma$-spaces are related to $E_{\infty}$-operads. I've found some old publications but was hoping there are better references out there. Maybe a textbook or lecture notes?

By $\Gamma$-spaces I mean functors $\Gamma^{op} \rightarrow \textbf{Top}$ between the skeleton of the category of finite sets and the category of topological spaces $\textbf{Top}$.

Comment: can you please list the old publication to avoid superfluous suggestions?

Comment: I think it was: 'HOMOLOGY OPERATIONS REVISITED' by FIEDOROWICZ and May (www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/PAPERS/39.pdf)

Comment: Section 2.5 of "Operads in Algebra, Topology and Physics" by Markl, Schnider, Stasheff may be helpful. This was available online for free at some point although I have just failed to find a link to post unfortunately.